# Javascript triggered sound without permission?

Tags: javascript, facebook, audio, notifications, chat

I need to get a web page to play a sound triggered by javascript when a chat message arrives, but when the sound plays, chrome asks me to give quick time permission

Facebook is a perfect example of what I'm looking for, how do they do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Answer (score 2):

QuickTime is a plug-in that requires permission before it runs by default in Chrome.  If you pick an audio format that is natively supported by the browser or even one that the built-in Adobe flash supports, then the browser will not think it needs Quicktime and will not ask for permission.

You could also configure your particular browser to allow QuickTime to run without asking for permission, but that would only be a fix for your particular browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the HTML5 Audio element instead (will only work on modern browsers, of course).

For an example, see http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/